# Do raspberry primocanes canes look different from second year growth?

Tags: raspberries

Is there a difference in, say, stem color or thorn size or texture, between black raspberry primocanes and second year plants? How can I tell between the two?

Comment: Your question caused me to search for images of black raspberries.  Found this. Not sure I believe it.  https://www.therike.com/products/60-seeds-giant-blackberry-black-berry-raspberry-seeds-huge-fruit-rubus-bush-fruit-jocad-giant-fruit-seeds

Comment: Where space is not a huge constraint, my low-effort raspberry pruning method is to cut all the canes off half the bed every other year (and cut the other half in the alternate year.) Saves trying to pick out old .vs. new growth. You still need to thin them.